# Rails 3 ignores PUT method when form partial displayed via jquery causing routing error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a model `Patients` that has many `Healthplans`.  I'm trying to update the healthplans of a patient by inserting the appropriate form using jquery when the "Add Insurance Plan" link is clicked.

The fields are properly inserted on click, but when the form is submitted, I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/patients/1472"
```

When I check the code generated by form_for, it is not creating the hidden field with the PUT method to override the default POST method.  This is causing the error, because there is no POST route for that url.  Interestingly, if I code the form directly within show.html.erb, it displays correctly and the hidden fields for the PUT method are properly generated.  It ONLY FAILS when I add the form partial with jquery.

I've spent hours tweaking the code, researching StackOverflow and the Almighty Google, haven't found mention of quite the same issue.

Here's my form:

```
<%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
    <%= fields_for :healthplans_attributes do |builder| %>
        <td><%= builder.text_field :company %></td> 
        <td><%= builder.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %></td>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= f.submit "Submit" %></td>
<% end %>
```

My controller (extraneous functions omitted):

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  def index

def show
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    @insurance = Patient.return_insurances(@patient)
    @pa = @patient.preauthorizations
    @programs = @patient.programs
    @billingitems = Claim.return_billingitems(@patient, params[:page])
    @address = Patient.return_address(@patient)
    @phone = Patient.return_phone(@patient)
  end

  def new
    @patient = Patient.new
    1.times { @patient.healthplans.build }
    1.times { @patient.preauthorizations.build }
  1.times { @patient.programs.build }
    render :url => 'new.html' , :layout => "false"
end

def new_insurance
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { @patient }
  end
end

  def create
#   raise params.inspect
    @patient = Patient.new(params[:patient])
    if @patient.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created patient."
      redirect_to @patient
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    if @patient.update_attributes(params[:patient])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated patient."
      redirect_to @patient
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

In my view show.html.erb, my link to Add Insurance Plan:

```
 <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <table id="insurances">&nbsp;</table>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <%= link_to "Add Insurance Plan", new_insurance_patient_path(:id => @patient.id), :remote => true %>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The new_insurance.js.erb file:

```
J(function(){
  var html = '<%= escape_javascript(raw render(:partial => 'add_insurance')) %>';
  J("#insurances").append(html);
});
```

Which renders the partial _add_insurance.html.erb:

```
<tr class="fields" >    
    <%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
    <%= fields_for :healthplans_attributes do |builder| %>
        <td><%= builder.text_field :company %></td> 
        <td><%= builder.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %></td>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= f.submit "Submit" %></td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

And finally, my routes.rb file:

```
Billspace::Application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.
  match 'patients/set_active_flag/:id', :to => 'patients#set_active_flag'
  match 'patients/active_list', :to =>'patients#active_list'
  match 'patients/inactive_list', :to => 'patients#inactive_list'
  match 'payments/show_payment_items/:id', :to => 'billingitems#show_payment_items'
  match 'claims/claiminfo/:id', :to => 'claims#claiminfo'
  match 'claiminfo/:id', :to => 'claims#claiminfo'
  match 'patients/new', :to => 'patients#new'

  match 'claims/new/create_claims', :to => 'claims#create_claims'

  match 'payments', :to => 'billingitems#index' 

  resources :billingitems

  resources :claims
  resources :providers
  resources :patients

  resources :patients do
    member do
      get 'new_program'
      get 'new_insurance'
    end
  end

  match 'signup', :to => 'users#new', :as =>'signup'
  match 'logout', :to =>'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
  match 'login', :to => 'sessions#new', :as => 'login'

  resources :sessions 
  resources :users 
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem (I'm using Rails 3.2.8).  It's been 6 months since you asked this question and you've probably long since solved it or given up, but I'll post this answer for the sake of future googlers.

It seems the problem here is that you, just as I did, have your form tag inside a **<tr>** but not inside any **<td>**.  This is fine for **<form>** tags but not for the **<div>** tag rails uses to enclose the hidden inputs, since visible (or potentially-visible) content such as **<div>** tags normally shouldn't be put in such a place.  Rails, apparently, has no problem with doing this when it generates a page from an .erb file, but jQuery will balk at being asked to do such a silly and *obviously* incorrect thing, and will silently discard the offending **<div>** along with all of its contents.  The solution that worked for me was to enclose the form tag in its own little invisible **<td>**, something like this:

```
<td style="display:none">
    <%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
</td>
```

This seems to satisfy jQuery that you aren't a madman who puts **<div>**'s directly inside of **<tr>**'s, and the form is duly submitted as a PUT.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer.  I'm sure I found a workaround for this, but it's good to know.